# dataAdapater.Fill(dataTable) throwing ArgumentNullException when dataTable is null

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I've a code something like below

```
 DataTable dtProjects=null;
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
        {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("stored procedure",conn))
               {
                 using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                     {
                            da.Fill(dtProjects);
                            return dtProjects;
                      }
                }
         }
```

When I execute above code da.Fill() method is throwing ArumentNullException

### Exception Description

ArumentNullException was caught,
value cannot be null.
parameter name: dataTable

Problem got solved when I create Object for DataTable but when I saw metadata of Fill() method it has **Only one Exception which is InvalidOperationException.** 
**My Question is why Fill() threw ArgumentNullException as it has only one exception in .net meta data**

I am using VS2010 and .Net4.0

Answer (score 0):

There are no checked exceptions in C# [1], so exceptions need to be documented somehow. As documentation can be incomplete, you might want to look at the source [2] to determine which exceptions could be thrown.

[1] https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/why-doesnt-c-have-checked-exceptions/

[2] https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs,83c50ff427350859